# No .cs files in inherited Web Forms site

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

First of all, I know ASP.NET MVC, but have very little/no experience with Web Forms.  I inherited a site today that is a Web Forms site.  Once I got to looking at it, it was quickly apparent that the .cs (code behind) files that go with the .aspx files are missing (or hidden somewhere).  I get an error page in the browser when I try to build because the files are missing.  The curious thing is that the live site is totally fine...so surely those files exist somewhere?...or maybe you don't need them?...like I said, today is my first day trying to tackle an old Web Forms site.

The files are not present in the local directories nor in Visual Studio.  Am I missing something...am I crazy...am I just a newb?  I attached some pics.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: When deploying a WebForms site you usually do not include the `.cs` files.  The `.dll(s)` are the only thing that matters. So if you grabbed this code from the deployed environment, you will likely not find the source with it.

Comment: I bet this is the issue.  I was just granted access to a server that I had to navigate without any instruction and I bet I stumbled upon the deployed code and not the source code.